# Expected number of players buying a product

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory

There is a continuum of players who want to buy a product. The utility to each player from that product is $q$. If he does not buy the product, his utility is zero. The random variable, $q$, has a uniform distribution over the interval $[x_1,y_1]$, where $x_1<y_1$. The players use a mixed strategy $z=\frac{1-\frac{q}{y_1}}{a-q}$ to buy the product, where $a>y_1$ is a constant and $x_1 \leq q \leq y_1$, i.e. a player buys the product with probability $z$. How can one calculate the expected number of buyers using this setup? If yes, how do we do that? If not, what other information is required?

Answer (score 0):

If we align all buyers in ascending order according to their willingness to pay, a buyer will buy the product only if his willingness to pay matches the price or is above it, set by market,in case of perfect competition, or a firm(s), in case of any of externality in the market.
So the expected number of buyers using your said setup can only be calculated if we happen to know the price existing in the market, since we happen to all other factors required to calculate expectation, i.e., range and a probability distribution function.